# How to access Object class from Kotlin in Java

Tags: kotlin

I am new to Kotlin. I have a kotlin Object class like

```
@Parcelize
object AddCard
```

I want to access it in a Java class. if I have to do so I read that i have to give @JVMStatic annotation to the object class.something like

```
@JVMStatic
@Parcelize
object AddCard
```

when I add the annotation it says

> This annotation is not applicable to target object.

How to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special.  You can access it from Java with just `AddCard.INSTANCE`.